How to format data for Hugging Face seamless-m4t-v2-large model deployed on Sagemaker for T2TT
I have deployed seamless-m4t-v2-large model from Hugging face to Sagemaker endpoint and would like to call predict on it but i can't any resources on how to format data for .predict() method in case of text-to-text translation.
Here are HF details:
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'facebook/seamless-m4t-v2-large',
    'HF_TASK':'automatic-speech-recognition'
}

I have tried cases similar to:
data = { 
  "inputs": "This is a sentence in English.",
  "task": "t2tt",
  "tgt_lang": "fr",
  "src_lang": "en"
}
result = predictor.predict(data)

but i'm getting:
An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary and could not load the entire response body.
Also this model is marked as automatic-speech-recognition on HF so i wonder should i keep it or maybe change it to something more suitable?
Any help is appreciated
